# Insert into hive from dataframe is not working

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert the records from dataframe into hive tables using below command. The command is successful but the target table is not loaded with records.

```
mergerdd.write.mode("append").insertInto("db.tablename")
```

I expect records to be loaded into hive table.

Comment: This works good for default databases. But, has some reported bugs with non-default db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check with my Solution. It worked for me.

```
df.repartition(1).write.format("csv").insertInto('db.tablename',overwrite=True) # CSV 
df.repartition(1).write.format("orc").insertInto('db.tablename',overwrite=True) # ORC
df.repartition(1).write.format("parquet").insertInto('db.tablename',overwrite=True) #PARQUET
```

Answer (score 0):

this way works for me via spark.sql

```
df.coalesce(#numberofoutputfile).createOrReplaceTempView(#temptablename)

spark.sql(f"insert into {db}.{tablename} select * from {temptablename}")
```

also `mergerdd` is an rdd or spark dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of achieving what you are trying to achieve:

```
df.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("db.tablename")
```

I use this all the time without any problems. 
Hope that helps.